# Files in a Library

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have a personal library in DB2 where all my outputs are saved. I would like to see the list of files and the size of those using IBM iNavigator. Is their a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look under File Systems -> Integrated File System -> The path where your file is stored. All paths are available there. If it is in the `Library` file system, look under `QSYS.LIB` for the library. If it is in the `IFS`, then look under the appropriate path off of `Root`. There are likely several other options. We can't tell you exactly because you haven't told us your path.